# How speedup qemu? My launch parameters very slow

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

Im try launch VM under windows 10 x64, qemu 4.0.92.0 on my rented VDS

> qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4G -accel tcg,thread=single -smp
>   cpus=1,cores=2,threads=2 -boot order=d  -drive
>   file=C:\Users\admin\docs\windows\windows.img,format=raw,if=virtio

*note: this lauch options above is worked, but VERY SLOW*

I try change different accelerators but always get -accel tcg,thread=single

with accel kvm I got this

> C:\Program Files\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: Invalid CPU
>   topology deprecated: sockets (0) * dies (1) * cores (2) * threads (2)
>   != maxcpus (1)
>       C:\Program Files\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: -machine accel=kvm: No accelerator found

Ofc I read manual, try different accels, only the tcg works.
Try add more threads = crash after windows logo

BTW , I can run android emulators with fll speed with no problem
SYSINFO: Intel i 2130 , 3.40
ram 8GB
Any help appreciated